# Rails - Is .first guaranteed to be the first created, or just the first fetched?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Let's assume I have many `User` records - if I call `User.first` is that guaranteed to be the first user that existed in the database or should I sort by `created_at` to make sure that the ordering is by `created_at`? Please note that I am using mongoid and not ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 0):

`User.first` returns the first user ordered by primary key (see section 1.1.3 of [Active Record Query Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-objects-from-the-database)).

Most of the time it will be first created item, but it's not guaranteed. Depends on how the DB has been populated. So you should use:

```
Client.order('created_at').first
```

Answer (score 0):

First returns the first object in the query. In your example calling `User.first` returns the first record in the `User.all` set of data. While this would by default be the first record in order of primary key, if you have placed any order conditions on the query (including a default scope on the model) it will return the first object based on the order given.

For example `User.all.order("last_name").first` would return the record with the first alphabetically ordered last name. Or `User.all.order("updated_at DESC").first` would return the most recently updated user.

If you have not set any ordering scopes on your query, the ordering will default to the order in which the records were created at and no other ordering would be necessary. For more info on the way these function, check out this [rails guides entry on **Active Record Query Interface**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html).